# Module importation in Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I am using Python 3.4

I have a directory structure that looks this:

```
A
   B
      c.py
      d.py
      __init__.py
   C
      e.py
      f.py
      __init__.py
   g.py
   __init__.py
```

From g.py I can import things from both B and C modules.

I need, in **e.py**, to import something from **c.py**

I tried:

```
import B
```

and

```
from B.c import stuff_I_need
```

For both I get the error:

```
"No module named B".
```

I also tried something like:

```
from A.B.c import stuff_I_need
```

I am further confused by the fact with an identical directory structure, I can make the imports I need with Python 2.7.

Can you help me figure out what's going on?

Solution:

```
PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3).

Answer (score 0):

When importing it looks at the the python folder for imports and the files in the local directory. If you want to import a file that is in neither of those, then I suggest using the `sys` module

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'file-path\A') # Folder A
import B.c
```

If you don't want to set the full file path then you can also just backtrack to the previous directory with this for the same effect.

```
sys.path.append('..') # Previous Directory
```

Comment: Alternatively, the package can be installed to site-packages depending on the purposes of `A`.  But @Steven-Summers is right, it has to be on your python path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did something similar: PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))

Answer (score 0):

You need to do either

```
from .B import c
```

or

```
import A.B.c
```

Reference:

- [What's New in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports)
- [PEP 328 - Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#abstract)